# How to bypass login screen after inactivity

Tags: login, suspend

How do I bypass the login page after waking screen from inactivity suspend? I have found old answers to this, but they do not apply to Ubuntu 20.04 and later. I got v. 22.10 and the answer is not in Settings-> Privacy, and not in Settings-> Display.  There is on/off option for login in Settings-> Users, but that is only for login on boot.

Thanks

Comment: please check if this key is available in 22.10  `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled`

Comment: Thanks.  I run that and the answer was true.  Can I use gsettings to switch off the screensaver lock?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false`

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I have just found that myself and it worked.